# Nginx rewrite rule: Add subfolder to URI if not there

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Hello I'm trying to write a Nginx rewrite rule that adds a subdirectory to my URL if it's missing.  For example, I need `http://example.com` to be re-written (and redirected) to `http://example.com/legacy-app`. Can't seem to find the proper example to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using this:

```
rewrite ^/$ /legacy-app/ last;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `rewrite` directive, but an exact match `location` block is most efficient:

```
location = / {
    return 301 /legacy-app;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.